# Running UCK causes zenity crashed

Tags: zenity

I was very satisfied with Ubuntu Customization kit on Ubuntu previous versions but with 12.04, it leads to crash zenity and disappear the GUI and nothing occur.I tried the old version of this package but the same result.Please help me.Thnx in advance.

Comment: can you please repost because link doesn't work. Thank you.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/129933/running-uck-causes-zenity-crashed/ This link is not working!

Answer (score 1):

I had no idea what Ubuntu Customization kit was, but I downloaded it so as to help you and I found out what causes the bug, I also found a solution to the problem, after a 5-6 min search of the code.
So, with some tricks on the code I managed to go till the screen that asks for the ISO, but I couldn't go further, as I didn't have an ISO downloaded, but I suspect that it should work fine from that point and after.

Ok, follow these steps:

1. **Open a terminal (*using Ctrl+Alt+T*) and give**: gksudo gedit /usr/lib/uck/gui.sh

   Gedit will open.
2. **Now, replace all the text in the opened file with this text: http://paste.ubuntu.com/961943/** (DO NOT select the numbers on the left)

   Save the file and close gedit and terminal.
3. **Re-run UCK**.

Please let me now if it works further than selecting the ISO image, because I've tested till that point only (cause as I said before, I don't have an ISO to test it out!)

Also, note that this is not a permanent fix, it will probably cause some bugs in case you click 'Cancel' etc, but it will at least not crush and let you do the work.

Comment: Thank u hakermania, u have done a marvelous job for me.Right now I am away from home but will conquer it with what u said and post the reply here as soon as I reach home.But let me say that it runs up to it allows me to select the language for the ISO but disappears the moment I click "ok" and only the message comes out as "the application zenity closed unexpectedly".

Comment: Yes beeju, the same happened to me, but I fixed it and it doesn't crush (closes unexpectedly) at least till the point that asks for the ISO file!

Comment: I am so pleased.I don't know what all those  texts you wrote on pastbin.I just entered my password for the build.It works!!!

Comment: But it failed at last.I went through all the lines on terminal before I close it.From this paste.ubuntu.com/962187 I thought the temp folder in my Home folder made this problem.So I removed it from there.On running the package,it failed again and I deleted both resolvconf folder and resolv.conf with root power.Now it said this http://paste.ubuntu.com/962263/

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything else about this :(

Comment: I will try again later, when I'll have more time and I'll try to fix it, once I've downloaded the 12.04 LTS iso, of course.

Comment: I will wait as I don't know about scripts but I continue try in Launchpad.Thanks for your follow up.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't manage to find where this errors stems from. I got the same error but I couldn't find anywhere in the uck executables something about resolv.conf file, so it's probably an external command to blame.

Comment: @hakermania as user164033 pointed out in an answer, your link for **Step 2** doesn't show anything, maybe it needs to be updated :)

Comment: It would be nice if you sent an email to the developers rather than trying to find your way around this bug ;)